# How can I use the reference parameter of the inner abstract class in JAVA

Tags: java, reference, abstract, inner-classes

There are an inner interface, an inner abstract class and an inner class in the outer class.

When I call the outerMethod() method of the OuterClass,

the method of AKindBiz class can only print the contents of the list.

Why the method of abstract class (CommonKindBiz) can't print anything?

```
public class OuterClass {

    public void outerMethod( ) throws Exception{
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1111");
        list.add("2222");

        KindBiz biz = new AKindBiz();
        biz.execute(list);
    }

    public interface KindBiz 
    {
        public void execute( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception;

        public void preExec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception;
        public void exec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception;
        public void postExec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception;
    }

    abstract public class CommonKindBiz implements KindBiz 
    {

        public void execute( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception{
                System.out.println("KindBiz.CommonKindBiz.execute ### inputList1 : " + inputList ); // Nothing printed.

                this.preExec(inputList);
                this.exec(inputList);
                this.postExec(inputList);
        }

        public void preExec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception
        {    
                System.out.println("KindBiz.CommonKindBiz.preExec ### inputList  : " + inputList );  // Nothing printed.
        }   

        public abstract void exec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception;

        public void postExec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception
        {           
                System.out.println("KindBiz.CommonKindBiz.postExec ### inputList : " + inputList );  // Nothing printed.
        }    
    }

    public class AKindBiz extends CommonKindBiz
    {
        @Override
        public void exec( ArrayList<String> inputList) throws Exception
        {           
                System.out.println("KindBiz.AKindBiz.exec ### inputList  : " + inputList ); // "1111", "2222" printed.
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't print anything"? It's not clear what's going wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet With that deep nesting of interfaces, class and an abstract class, does it not seem like a design issue ? =)

Comment: @LittleChild: Well it's far from ideal, but I'd like to know the problem the OP is running into and fix that first, then fix everything else...

Comment: This doesn't even compile, `prinfln` doesn't exist and `input` is undefined in the abstract class, also preExec, etc are taking 1 param not 2..

Comment: you call all function in single parameter *inputList*. but your all function have 2 parameters.

Comment: @JonSkeet there are too many problems to fix. Maybe the OP needs to revise the basics first =D

Comment: Cleaned up version: http://ideone.com/Woxkdw

Comment: While simplifing the code, I had many mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.prinfln("KindBiz.CommonKindBiz.execute ### inputList1 : " + inputList ); // Nothing printed.
```

that line seems to be the issue. It is `println()`. Everywhere in your code you have `prinfln()`. Replace those with `println()`

**Update:**
As RC and subash pointed out, your methods declare that they will take 2 parameters but you only give them 1 when you call them. You need to give them 2 or change the signature of your method.

***Please use an IDE.*** These errors like mismatch of parameters can very easily be pointed out by IDE and with a proper description of what is wrong and how to go about fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to make it compile.

I tested it, and all lines are printed. I do not believe there is a problem.

Comment: I also have a successful test. Maybe the original codes have another problem which is not associated with inner abstract calss. Next time I will ask another problem after checking the code. Thank you.